# At wits end with powershell add-adgroupmember

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been trying to add users to groups from a CSV for hours now using `Add-ADGroupmember`. I always get the error-

> Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again."

Here is the script I am using -

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
import-csv y:\d1.csv -Delimiter ";" | Foreach-Object {add-adgroupmember -Identity $_.group -Members $_.name}
```

> ```
> group;name
> "CN=example,OU=example,DC=example,DC=example,DC=example";"CN=example,OU=example,OU=example,DC=example,DC=example,DC=example"
> "CN=example-AE,OU=example,DC=example,DC=example,DC=example";"CN=example,OU=example,OU=example,DC=example,DC=example,DC=example"
> ```

I have 2000 users to add to around 100 groups, maybe there is a better way? Is there something simple I am missing here?

Comment: Still no joy, is there a way to output to a txt file?

Comment: To troubleshoot these types of problems (reading files and working with the current object) instead of using the actual cmdlet, try just `Write-Host` and see if the data looks correct.  From there, copy the output and test it and if that works you should be all set to run the command fully.

Comment: Isn't write-host for writing strings to the screen, you can output the current commands?

Comment: Yes, but I use that to make sure my loop in PowerShell is getting the data I want and outputting the correct string.  It's actually for writing output to the console but its pretty helpful for troubleshooting commands.

Comment: Cheers, I am checking the proper syntax and I am going to try it now.

Comment: Remember that although using a Distinguished Name (as a string) *should* work for the `*-ADGroupMember` cmdlets, they are documented as expecting an **ADGroup** object for the `-Identity` parameter. The `Write-Host` test should verify what is being passed, but you could add a `Get-ADGroup` command which is then passed to `Add-ADGroupMember` in your pipeline.

Comment: When I use get-ADgroup with a DN it doesn't work, so I will try using an adgroup object thank you.

Comment: Alright with a write-host csv$ in front of the script it shows that every line starts with - @{group;name= . I assume this is normal? Without using DNs I can manually add a user to a group, so I stopped using DNs and I still get the same error. I know the CSV can be accessed by the script because it outputs everything with write-host. At this point I think there is nothing more to be done with this script and I am going to look for another.

Comment: Well it looks like it is working now, I am not really sure why. I started again, and the original file I am working from which was a google doc with 16 columns of groups per user I edit to be one group a line while I tested. I left the file as is and just did this with the script - 

import-module ActiveDirectory
import-csv C:\cache\lighterside.csv | Foreach-Object {add-adgroupmember -Identity $_.classcode2 -Members $_.Email}
import-csv C:\cache\lighterside.csv | Foreach-Object {add-adgroupmember -Identity $_.classcode3 -Members $_.Email}

Comment: ETC

And it looks like it is working, the users are appearing in the groups. I am running it from the local disk currently but it did work running it from the mapped share as well. So I am not sure what is different now, the only thing I can think of is that it was formatted strangely or hidden characters or something I did when saving the csv the first time and second time. Thank you for the great advice and help.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes problems such as this are caused by unexpected data (or lack of) in the input data file. I have seen this as more of a problem with `Get-Content` than `Import-Csv` but...

Ensure that you aren't passing blank data from the CSV (e.g. blank lines at the bottom of the file, etc.). You might try piping the output from the Import-Csv cmdlet through a `Where-Object` check to ensure that only valid data gets to the `Foreach-Object` loop:

```
Import-Csv y:\d1.csv -Delimiter ";" | 
  Where-Object{-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.group)} |
    Foreach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.group -Members $_.name}
```

Clearly you can perform a similar check on the Name property too.

Comment: `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` might be preferable, although it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I will do some troubleshooting
this is a long version of your code. and trying to get-adgroup and get-aduser will make sure is it valid before you can go on.

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
$csv = import-csv y:\d1.csv -Delimiter ";" 
Foreach-Object ($c in $csv ) {
get-adgroup $c.group
get-aduser $c.name

get-adgroup $c.group | add-adgroupmember Members $c.name
}
```

you can even try to limit this to first line by doing this

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
$csv = import-csv y:\d1.csv -Delimiter ";" 
$c = $csv[0]
get-adgroup $c.group
get-aduser $c.name
get-adgroup $c.group | add-adgroupmember Members $c.name
```

Comment: With the first script I get the error -                                                                "At \\zeus\Shares\Scripts\Dashboardcsv\mylittlecutelittle.ps1:3 char:20
+ Foreach-Object ($c in $csv ) {
+                    ~~
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
At \\zeus\Shares\Scripts\Dashboardcsv\mylittlecutelittle.ps1:3 char:19
+ Foreach-Object ($c in $csv ) {
+                   ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At \\zeus\Shares\Scripts\Dashboardcsv\mylittlecutelittle.ps1:3 char:28
+ Foreach-Object ($c in $csv ) " Sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: The second script gets the error - "Get-ADGroup : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.
At \\zeus\Shares\Scripts\Dashboardcsv\mylittlecutelittle.ps1:4 char:13
+ get-adgroup $c.group" which is certainly showing that nothing is getting pulled from the CSV.

Comment: if your first line doesn't work, then it is best to move that file locally. you must at least able to run $csv = import-csv .\blah.csv -delimiter ";"   if you have issues with that, then we have problem. also what powershell version you use? try, $psversiontable

Comment: When I run this I don't get anything back, what should or shouldn't I see? I will try running it on a local disk although the DC it is on currently I did try running it on to the same effect. I am running powershell version 5.0.10586.122

Comment: I added write-host to the front of it and it did feed back everything in the csv.

Comment: we will work 1 line by 1 line. we are doing on 2nd script. so after you run $csv = import-csv .... if you type $csv.count, do it return the count of the line? then after that if you run $c = $csv[0], then type $c | fl, do it return 2 line (group and name). then when you run get-adgroup $c.group, do it return a valid group? and get-aduser $c.name, do it return a valid name?

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV is using semi-colon `;` as a delimeter, then you need to tell that to `Import-Csv`:

```
import-csv y:\d1.csv -Delimiter ';'
```

Comment: I apologize, I have that in the latest version of the script but didn't copy it here for some reason. I thought that since the distinguished name had a bunch of commas I should change the delimiter to be safe. Have edited it into the OP now.

Comment: And I'd read the CSV into a variable.  `$csv = import-csv Y:\d1.csv -delim ';'`  Then  you can use `$csv.group` and `$csv.name` which is a lot easier to read/follow.